# Named Graph Support in MarkLogic

Tags: sparql, marklogic, marklogic-8, named-graphs

I am not understanding how `FROM NAMED` graph is supported in MarkLogic. I am experimenting with SPARQL queries to find which collection the triples are coming from. The result is really confusing. For example:

```
select *
FROM <http://x.y.z/c>
FROM NAMED <http://x.y.z/c>
WHERE {
#  GRAPH ?g 
  {?s ?p ?o}
  }
```

returns a set of triple. However, if I un-comment the line `# GRAPH ?g`, the following error is returned:

> `[1.0-ml] XDMP-COLLXCNNOTFOUND: amped-qconsole:qconsole-sparql($query, (), (), (), ()) -- Collection lexicon not enabled`

and highlight is on the `WHERE {` line.

Additionally, the following works and returns a set of triples:

```
select *
FROM <http://x.y.z/c>
WHERE {
  {?s ?p ?o}
  }
```

but not this:

```
select *
FROM NAMED <http://x.y.z/c>
WHERE {
  {?s ?p ?o}
  }
```

it returns an empty set. Adding the `GRAPH ?g` line causes the same error as above being returned. I am really confused. Can someone give an explanation of the behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MarkLogic uses collections in its implementation of graphs. There is a note in the [GRAPH keyword documentation](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/semantics/semantic-searches#id_91387) that mentions the need for the collection lexicon.

> You must enable the collection lexicon when you use a GRAPH construct in a SPARQL query. You can enable the collection lexicon from the database configuration pages or the Admin Interface.

I'll add that you can also enable the collection lexicon through the [Management API](http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/PUT/manage/v2/databases/[id-or-name]/properties).